# Exception in component tDBOutput_1 (InsigniaImages) java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: sqlType=2003

Tags: sql, exception

I have 2 columns in my source Access DB, Column 1 has serial number and column 2 has images attached. I got a java script which works fine when the first row has image attached as part of the second column. But when the first row of second column is not having any images attached script fails with the error. The data type used in Oracle column for importing the image is BLOB.

Exception in component tDBOutput_1 (InsigniaImages)
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: sqlType=2003

I am importing the images from Access DB and exporting it to Oracle DB using talend tool. I am very new to Java and I am not understanding what changes i need to make in the script. Below is the Java script which i am trying to execute

```
    
Object obj = rs_tDBInput_1.getObject(2);
net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment[] objArr =((net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment[])obj);

System.out.println(objArr.length);
System.out.println("Error exception");
if (obj != null && objArr.length>0 ) {

 net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment att = (((net.ucanaccess.complex.Attachment[])obj)[0]);


 System.err.println("Attachment Name: " + att.getName());


 row2.bytea = att.getData();
 
}
```

Please help me with this issue.

I tried changing the Output column data type to Raw but it didn't work. I want the images to be imported in BLOB format in oracle DB